# drawing commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams

I solved the problem I mentioned below, thank you very much for your suggestions.

I want to use the diagram  to appear in the article. I want to set the size according to the article in this example. I do not know whether I could express myself correctly. Thank you for all suggestions.

[image]Could you help me for drawing the following diagram ?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us the code ...

Comment: I'd suggest you to read [Prof. van Duck's TUGBoat article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf), (which was recently made publicly available) in which he thoroughly explains the basics of Ti*k*Z styles ans gives an example of a diagram. With that article you have the necessary tools to create the diagram you're asking us to do for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I cannot draw it immediately and I need this diagram as soon as possible. I am not good drawing diagram at latex and do not have enough time. I am trying to conclude my paper in a few days.

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca Everyone here's got things to do. People who answer questions here do it as a hobby, not as a job, so it's unlikely that someone will rush into drawing the complete diagram for you, simply because that's *your* job. Perhaps someone with enough free time will do all of it, perhaps they'll give you a start as Diaa did, and perhaps they will vote to close your question as "too broad" or something like that. That's why "do-it-for-me" questions are usually not very well received.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  I'm sorry to misunderstand myself. I know the people here are doing it to help someone. I didn't want to do my own job completely. Diaa's example was a good example   what I wanted to do. I can't use the latex as well as you. What I want is an example that I can apply to my diagram. I'm sorry for taking your time...

Comment: Please, check my answer edit and spend considerable time learning tikz. Have a nice day `:)`

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca No need for apologies :) As I said, with this type of question you might or might not get the answer you want. That's why I pointed you a resource for you to learn to draw your own diagrams so that you don't depend on other people when you're short on time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a complete answer to your question. It is just a good example to start with knowing that there are many approaches to your problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth]
    \matrix (dag)  [matrix of nodes,%
    nodes={rectangle,draw},
    column sep={2cm,between origins},
    row sep={2cm,between origins},
    ampersand replacement=\&] {
        \& |(1)| Start  \&                                  \\
        |(11)| A            \& |(12)| B     \& |(13)| C \\
      \& |(21)| End         \&                                  \\
    };

    \draw (1) to (11);
    \draw (1) to (12);
    \draw (1) to (13);
    \draw (11) to (12);
    \draw (12) to (13);
    \draw (11) to (21);
    \draw (12) to (21);
    \draw (13) to (21);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

I am not the TikZpert here in the slightest, but I spent some time converting your hand drawing into a simple code. Please, study it well since do-it-for-me questions are the most hated ones here `:)`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,]
    \matrix (dag)  [matrix of nodes,%
    nodes={rectangle,draw},
    column sep={3ex},
    row sep={10ex,between origins},
    ampersand replacement=\&] {
        \& |(01)| $\sigma$-rigid  \& \\
        |(11)| strongly $\sigma$-symmetric \& |(12)| strongly symmetric  \& |(13)| symmetric \\
        |(21)| strongly $\sigma$-skew reversible \& |(22)| strongly reversible  \& |(23)| reversible \\
        |(31)| strongly $\sigma$-IFP \& |(32)| strongly IFP  \& |(33)| IFP \\
      \& |(41)| Abelian \&  \\
    };



    \draw (01.south west) -- (11.north east); \draw (01) -- (12); \draw (01.south east) -- (13.north west);
    \draw[<->] (11) -- node[midway,right]{text} (21); \draw (21) -- (31); \draw (31.south east) -- (41.north west);
    \draw (12) -- (22); \draw (22) to (32); \draw (32) -- (41);
    \draw[<->] (13) -- (23); \draw (23) -- (33); \draw (33.south west) -- (41.north east);

    \draw (11) -- (12); \draw (12) -- (13); \draw (12) -- (13);
    \draw (21) -- (22); \draw (22) -- (23); \draw (22) -- (23);
    \draw (31) -- node[above] {dummy} (32); \draw (32) -- (33); \draw (32) -- (33);


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]